# Security Role is not Reflecting the changes to User

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011

Question is regarding the Dynamics CRM 2011. Let suppose for User 'A' we change the security role from 'SR1' to 'SR2'. But, when I login with User 'A', it still show all the access and priviliges of 'SR1'.

If after changing the security role from 'SR1' to 'SR2', then do 'IISReset' and login with User 'A'. Now User 'A' can have an access and priviliges of 'SR2'.

Why it is not working w/o 'IISReset'? Any idea.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you give an example of the different privileges in SR2 compared to SR1?

Comment: Hmmm. SR1 has CRUD on Entity1, while SR2 has CRUD on Entity2. Btw, this issue start appearing after applying Update Rollup 5.

Comment: We have a virtual flock of development servers, 7 in total. All initially identical. They have been used for 3 months, and one of the servers is showing this issue now for no specific reason. Security roles added do not reflect before iisreset, and also sitemap changes, customizations etc. show the same behavior. I am trying to figure it out and will post an answer if I do, but the common response on the net seems to be "rebuild the server". Challenge accepted!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried clearing the browser cache after you switch the roles?

Comment: Yes. Even open a new IE window as well. Btw, this issue start appearing after applying Update Rollup 5.

Comment: Further questions: Are you testing the roles on the app server? (Should'nt matter, but just in case try another machine). Is IE set to Windows authentication? Is the site set as trusted?